# Folding Python docstrings

Tags: folding, filetype-python

According to the [WIKI](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Syntax_folding_of_Vim_scripts), scripts can be folded based on syntax. Does anyone have a solution to fold Python docstrings?

Basically, all I need is to fold `""" text between triple quotation marks """`, like this:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to fold *only* docstrings, or docstrings *in addition* to folding Python code?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, just docstrings. So far, I was unable to achive _reliable_ python folding similar to full-fledged IDEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few funky factors at play that we should consider when playing with folds (they are complicated and not easy to understand without digging into the docs..)

- setting `foldmethod` to `syntax` was my issue when I was fighting fold but lets take a look at the docs for more info..

> SYNTAX                                          *fold-syntax*
>
> A fold is defined by syntax items that have the "fold" argument.
>   |:syn-fold|
>
> The fold level is defined by nesting folds.  The nesting of folds is
>   limited with 'foldnestmax'.
>
> Be careful to specify proper syntax syncing.  If this is not done
>   right, folds may differ from the displayed highlighting.  This is
>   especially relevant when using patterns that match more than one line.
>   In case of doubt, try using brute-force syncing:
>
> ```
>     :syn sync fromstart
> ```

The main thing to note is the `sync fromstart` this is a useful helper if you have regex that would match throughout the file and only want to catch the header. In your case you should be able to ignore this but just something to be aware of.

- top down regex scanning

Since the `"""` is fairly predictable we can simplify the `start` and `end` to look something like this:

```
syn region foldImports start='"""' end='"""' fold keepend
```

For both the `start` and `end` we are just trying to match on `'"""'`(or regexp) for the script tags. I did not test the above code out as I'm not much of a python guy but I bet you can get it figured out from here.

Comment: Thanks! It works after adding the line to ~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim and manually setting `foldingmethod` to `syntax` in buffer.

Comment: ...but breaks docstrings highlights. Life is tough.

Comment: damn.. I personally have folding turned off in my config with a profane comment regarding my feelings towards the feature :| hopefully a bit more regex hacking can get things working (id check plugins [grep fold keywords] if its almost there)

Comment: I used the syntax region definitions given at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16051080/455009 to target docstrings to be highlighted as comments, without affecting normal triple-quoted strings. Try those with `fold` added to the options, and it works pretty well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better method which will preserve all highlighting inside triple-quoted strings:

```
syn region  pythonString matchgroup=pythonTripleQuotes 
      \ start=+[uU]\=\z('''\|"""\)+ end="\z1" keepend fold
      \ contains=pythonEscape,pythonSpaceError,pythonDoctest,@Spell
```

Add this to `~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim`.

This command is taken exactly from `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/python.vim` and only has the `fold` keyword added. Why does this preserve highlighting when Dan's answer doesn't? The key is that this has:

```
contains=pythonEscape,pythonSpaceError,pythonDoctest
```

Normally, Vim applies only *one* syntax region, but with `contains=` you can tell it that a syntax region can *contain* other syntax regions.

It's also highlighted as a `String` because it does:

```
HiLink pythonString           String
```

Just defining a *syntax region* is not enough, you need to link this to a *highlight group*.